# How to make a state name dynamic?

Tags: reactjs

I am using `this.state.stateName` which state name is defined at getInitialState function at the beginning. If I want the `stateName` to be dynamic, how can do it?
I tried this but it did not work.

```js
roductButtonClicked:function(obj){
  if( this.state.obj.objectID  == "")
    alert("null")
 }
```

Comment: Curious, why do you need this? Can you not have a fixed `state` but storing dynamic object?

Comment: I need it when I am sending an object to a function.

Comment: What do you mean with 'dynamic'? Do you want to check whether `obj` is in your state? Then you could do `if (this.state.stateobject === obj)`.